# Unable to update the data on CSV file from Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have some data in CSV format which needs to be updated from Visual Basic code.

While updating the record, I am getting the error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Updating data in a linked table is not supported by this ISAM.

I have created a DSN named as "dsncsv".

Here is my code:

```
Dim ExcelCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim ExcelRs As New ADODB.Recordset

ExcelCon.ConnectionString = "dsncsv"
ExcelCon.Open

Dim SqlCmd As New ADODB.Command
SqlCmd.ActiveConnection = ExcelCon

SqlCmd.CommandText = "update test1.csv set Accoun='" & NM & "'"
SqlCmd.Execute
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite an answer, but what you are trying to do should be possible.  Can you show the source of the DSN  you are using, or make it part of the code directly, rather than referencing "dsncsv".  DSNs are a very irritating thing sometimes.

You might try switching to [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) instead of going through ado for this.  That library works quite well for this kind of work.

From the site:

> You can strong type your flat file (fixed or delimited) simply describing a class that maps to each record and later read/write your file as an strong typed .NET array